# rewrite forms GET data with htaccess

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Sorry if is a dummy question but I don't really know how to get it to work the following issue
I have a form whats url after submission looks as it follows

```
sites/example.php?category=Notebooks&prod_group=Apple&product=&customer_type=&voucher_type=
```

What I want is to rewrite this url on submit and the expected result should be

```
/folder/Notebooks/Apple
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to generate the URL and use mod-rewrite on the server the other way round. For server side there are [many solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) already.

Comment: First of all thank you for the tip. I'm using jqueries on .submit(); to submit the form and if I give a try with htaccess RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$                  /sites/example.php?category=$1    [L] is working but not in the way as I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you've added the rewrite rules on the server side, you can use the following jQuery, given that your form has an id `formId` and other input has corresponding ids:

```
// Set event handler
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formId").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "/folder/" +
                               encodeURI($("#category").val()) + "/" +
                               encodeURI($("#prod_group").val());
    });
});
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

As for the server setup for rewrite, try figure it out yourself as it is quite simple.